# Spacing and Page Break Issues for long equations. The aligned and align* dilemma

Tags: equations, align, page-breaking

Basically, for one long string of equations, I need to be able to have it continue over multiple pages.  I also need there to be a regular new paragraph space between the Title of the page and the string of equations.  I only need this for this particular equation, and need everything else to remain the same.

The `aligned` environment allows for the spacing to be exactly as I desire, but doesn't allow the page break.

The `align*` environment allows for the page break, but puts additional white space under the title, which I cannot have.

Is there a way for me to have both the things I desire simultaneously?

Answer (score 2):

Insert the instruction `\allowdisplaybreaks` in the preamble, after loading the `amsmath` package. And, instead of using the `\title` and `\maketitle` machinery, just type `\begin{center} \Huge <Title String> \end{center}`.